# How to build this array?

Tags: php, arrays

Im pretty new in php and Im having a little trouble in building an array, I want to reduce an array of multiple keys ($array) and values so I can get an array($namesArray) with only a couple of those keys with their respective values:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

        $namesArray[] = array(

            array("id" => $array[$i]["id"]),
            array("value"=>$array[$i]["value"]),
            array("value2"=>$array[$i]["value2"]),
            array("value3"=>$array[$i]["value3"])

        );
        /*
        $namesArray[] = array(

            ("id" => $array[$i]["id"]),
            ("value"=>$array[$i]["value"]),
            ("value2"=>$array[$i]["value2"]),
            ("value3"=>$array[$i]["value3"])

            );
*/
    }   
echo json_encode($namesArray);
```

I get a json with this structure:

```
[
    [{
        "id": "3"
    }, {
        "value": "Test"
    }],
    [{
        "id": "4"
    }, {
        "value": "Test"
    }]
]
```

Expecting:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "value": "Test",
        "value2":"value2"
    },{
        "id": "4",
        "value": "Test",
        "value2":"value2"
    }
]
```

I've tried the commented lines, thats how I would expect the code to be, with no result. I hope someone can help me to see my mistake. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){ 

    $namesArray[] = array(
      "id"     => $array[$i]["id"],
      "value"  => $array[$i]["value"],
      "value2" => $array[$i]["value2"],
      "value3" => $array[$i]["value3"]
    );

}
```

Hope this helps.